# Aliases for fonts in CSS

Tags: css, fonts, alias, font-face

I've just got into using @font-face. One of the unexpected perks is that instead of using the proper font name I can choose a more useful one, which is useful for reskinning

e.g instead of

```
@font-face {
   font-family: Museo Slab;
   src: ...
}
```

I can have

```
@font-face {
   font-family: Branding Font A;
   src: ...
}
```

So throughout my site I can then have e.g.

```
h1 {
  font-family: Branding Font A, Georgia, Serif;
}
```

... pretty useful as the site I'm working on will be syndicated, and I can easily just serve up different @font-face definitions for different publishers.

After that lengthy preamble, my question is "Is there a way to have an alias for one of the regular webfonts?" So that I can have eg "Body Text" as an alias for Arial, but such that I could change the "Body Text" @font-face declaration to use a different font if I wanted to.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer is no. But if there is a way I'd really like to know about it!

One way that *might* sorta work is:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: Alias;
   src: local('Arial');
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed this. Works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this the same way you do other web fonts by uploading the Arial font files to your server and declaring them the same way you would your other `@font-face` declarations, pointing the `src` to these files.  Regardless of the fact that these are standard web fonts, I'm not sure if there are licensing issues with this technique however.